# Stateful Builder not updating list in flutter while using interactiveScrollViewer

Tags: flutter, scroll, flutter-layout, updating, stateful

I'm using InteractiveScrollViewer and list is not updating on add and update function so i used StatefulBuilder for CardList. Now its working fine for same page but if i pushed another page i.e. endDrawer and update item there when i pop the page, no effect is shown in page.

```
StatefulBuilder(
                              builder:
                                  (BuildContext context,
                                          StateSetter _setState) =>
```

I'm updating item list in some function that is run when drawer is closed. I'm not able to send _setstate in this function as this function is global function.

what other techniques i can use for nested Scroll views.

Edit:

```
 bloc.getAllFoodItems(_id).then((value) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        _itemList = value;
        if (menuItemsList != null && menuItemsList.length != 0)
          for (int i = 0; i < menuItemsList.length; i++) {
            if (menuItemsList[i].id != null) {
              int ls = -1;
              if (_itemList != null)
                ls = _itemList
                    .indexWhere((item) => item.itemID == menuItemsList[i].id);

              if (ls != -1) {
                setState(() {
                  menuItemsList[i].quantity = _itemList[ls].quantity;
                });
              } else
                setState(() {
                  menuItemsList[i].quantity = 0;
                });
            }
          }
      });
    });
```

this code runs when draws is closed.

Comment: Can you shows us the function that runs when the `Drawer` is closed?

Comment: endDrawer: DrawerPage(
          callback: setDrawerOpened,
        ),

Comment: void setDrawerOpened(bool isOpen) {
    print(isOpen);
    if (!isOpen) {
      _fetchCount();
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is State Management.

When you say that you're updating from another page, then main issue is that your Drawer is probably not saving the state globally, so any page that wants to get the information to build the CardsList, will use the same information.

Now the main decision point is on deciding which State Management system you'd like to use. You could have any of the following or even more: Provider, Bloc, InheritedWidget, etc.
Here a list from the official Flutter docs on many options:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

PS: For simple apps I would recommend MobX or GetX, as it reduces the boilerplate.

Comment: I'm using bloc and updating quantity of item from list coming from bloc.

Comment: list is updated but not showing up due to _setState of each card.

Comment: @B.Ayaz could you please add your bloc code and the code you use to update the state as well? Otherwise I won't be able to help you in details

Comment: void setDrawerOpened(bool isOpen) {
    print(isOpen);
    if (!isOpen) {
      _fetchCount();
    }
  }

Comment: Added complete function in question